# Como criar função genérica para inputs diferentes

Tags: jquery, ajax

Possuo 3 `inputs`, onde cada um deverá utilizar a mesma função de *autocomplete*. Porém, cada um realizará a consulta com seu respectivo `val()`.

Como devo alterar o código abaixo, para que essa função trabalhe de maneira "genérica" para estes `inputs`? Ou seja, sem que haja a necessidade de passar no **data** do AJAX, os três valores em paralelo (até porque somente um será utilizado de cada vez).

Obs.: no retorno do AJAX, também preciso tratar exibindo uma resposta ao usuário ou preenchendo o *autocomplete* para aquele respectivo `input`.

```
$(function () {
    $("#suporteFrontal, #suporteTraseiro, #suporteUnico").on('change paste keyup', function () {
        $("#suporteFrontal, #suporteTraseiro, #suporteUnico").autocomplete({
            minLength: 1,
            appendTo: '#modalCortina',
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "actions/consultar-suporte.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    data: {
                        acao: 'autocomplete',
                        modeloProduto: $("#modeloProduto").val(),
                        descSuporte: $("#suporteFrontal").val(),
                        descSuporteI: $("#suporteTraseiro").val(),
                        descSuporteII: $("#suporteUnico").val(),
                        fixacaoSuporte: $('#fixacaoSuporte').val(),
                        tipoSuporte: $('#tipoSuporte').val()
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data == "") {
                            $("#colSupFrontal p").html('<p class="at-error">Suporte não encontrado.</p>');
                        } else {
                            $("#colSupFrontal p").remove();
                            response(data);
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                $("#suporteFrontal").val(ui.item.descricao);
                carregarDados();
                return false;
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#suporteFrontal").val(ui.item.descricao);
                return false;
            }
        }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $("<li>").append("<strong>Código: </strong>" + item.codigo + "&nbsp; | &nbsp; <strong>Descrição: </strong>" + item.descricao + "<br>").appendTo(ul);
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Não entendo muito de autocomplete, mas vc pode pegar o valor do input que está enviando dados com: `$('#'+event.target.id).val();` ou pegar o id desse input com `event.target.id;`.